# giving action property a string(instead of a full address) via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to give just a string to action property on `<form>` .see example [Click TRY IT](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_action)

the thing that i can'T understand is this where it gets the http part of it. As seen in here

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that if they'd used `getAttribute("action")` it would only have returned `form_action.asp` - when directly calling `.action` it is fetching the value parsed by the browser (thereby adding the domain to create a full URL) whereas `getAttribute` actually gets the value of the attribute

Comment: can i do it without .action

Comment: Of course, as I said in my comment, you can use `.getAttribute("action")` which gets the actual value of the attribute (only "form_action.asp". Or are you after getting `http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just read the function of the code, you might have noticed that the part was populated by the javaScript code. Here is the function

```
function myFunction() // executed when button is clicked
{
var x = document.getElementById("myForm").action; // get action attribute
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x; // write it
}
```

This would get the form's action. And show it inside the demo element.

The page name is given inside the `action` attribute. And the DOMAIN name is added automatically by the server, so that the request is complete URL now. That's why, the part is added automatically in the string that is returned.

Comment: this DOMAİN name added which part of HTML. i mean where it add it

Comment: It just appends it to the response that is provided to you .. It is accessed from the Browser's URL bar...

Answer (score 0):

Relative and absolute urls

**relative**

```
<form id="myForm" action="form_action.asp">
```

IS just the same as the **absolute**

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://www.domain.com/form_action.asp">
```

The javascript

```
document.getElementById("myForm").action;
```

will return the absolute ( actual ) url and path whether set relatively or not.

---

**If you want to get the actual value set in the 'action' attribute, can use:**

```
document.getElementById("myForm").getAttribute("action");
```